# Python Ghost Bot

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Unlike many questions about this topic, mine is not homework.  I built a [Ghost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_%28game%29) bot  that works.  My ultimate goal is to build a Poker bot as a hobby, but Ghost seems like a much easier game to think about to start with.

My code in question is the following:

```
def computer_prompt(playerName,word_string):
  length_string = len(word_string)
  for possibilities in wordlist:
    if possibilities[:length_string].lower() == word_string:
      if len(possibilities) > 3 and len(possibilities) % 2 != 0:
        if check_game.is_valid_word(possibilities[length_string],wordlist):
          if not check_game.word_formed(possibilities[:length_string + 1],wordlist):
            print(possibilities)
            return possibilities[:length_string + 1]
```

For now, I just want the computer to always go second, the human to always go first.  The issue is that while the computer beats me almost all the time, there are a few times where I can still outsmart him.  For example, if I play "h", then he plays "a", then I play "z", then he plays "a", then I play "r", then he throws an error (because he does not admit defeat :)).

How can I change it so that he knows not to say "a" following my saying "z" in this situation?  Obviously I could code this example as an exception, but I'm wondering the general solution to this problem.  Generally speaking, the computer beats me now because he looks for a list of all possible words that will end on me before deciding which letter to pick.  But in the "hazard" example he simply gets stuck, and I want him to know that he will get stuck a few moves ahead so that he doesn't get in the position in the first place...

Much thanks in advance!

**ADDED 9/27**

For anyone interested, the following code seems to be a bit better than what I had previously.  Still not perfect, though...:

```
def all_possibilities(word_string, length_string):
  possibilities = []
  for possibility in wordlist:
      if possibility[:length_string].lower() == word_string:
        possibilities.append(possibility)
  return possibilities

def clear_loser(possibilities):
  clear_losers = []
  for item in possibilities:
      if len(item) % 2 == 0:
        clear_losers.append(item)
  return clear_losers

def first_n_letters(sub_optimal_computer_possibilities, length_string):
  first_n_Letters = []
  for item in sub_optimal_computer_possibilities:
    first_n_Letters.append(item[:length_string + 1])
  return list(set(first_n_Letters))

def existing_Optimal_Move(FIRSTNLETTERS,first_letters_of_clear_losers):
  length_sub_opt_list = len(FIRSTNLETTERS)
  new_list = []
  for item in FIRSTNLETTERS:
    if not item in first_letters_of_clear_losers:
      new_list.append(item)
  return new_list

def computer_prompt(word_string):
  length_string = len(word_string)
  possibilities = all_possibilities(word_string, length_string)
  clear_losers = clear_loser(possibilities) #Create list of words that will end on computer
  sub_optimal_computer_possibilities = [x for x in possibilities if x not in clear_losers] #Create list of words that will end on human (including words that might be suboptimal for me because smart human will make it end on me before getting to this word
  FIRSTNLETTERS = first_n_letters(sub_optimal_computer_possibilities, length_string)
  first_letters_of_clear_losers = first_n_letters(clear_losers, length_string)
  optimalMove = existing_Optimal_Move(FIRSTNLETTERS, first_letters_of_clear_losers)
  if optimalMove:
    print("OPTIMAL MOVE")
    for item in optimalMove:
        #print(optimalMove)
      return item[:length_string + 1]   
  else:
    for item in FIRSTNLETTERS:
        #print(FIRSTNLETTERS)
      return item[:length_string + 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the ternary search tree data structure:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree

You could build a ternary search tree from your wordlist. Then you can have your computer loop through the children of your current position in the tree. He will eliminate any losing moves (a letter choice has no children), then loop through all their children. If any of the computer's possible moves has all losing children (they have no children themselves) then he will pick that choice because it guarantees a win.

While looping through he will eliminate any moves that guarantee loss. If he has no remaining moves, that means every move will cause him to lose, so he will just choose random letters until he loses. Otherwise he will choose the move which has the least possible ways he can lose, or the most ways he can win, possibly a linear combination of the two with constants determined experimentally. You will need clever loops or a recursive function.

Finally if you want him to use machine learning, you may want to have a dictionary such as `memory = {}` then every time he plays and loses he will add a list of his choices to the memory and avoid that pattern next time. He can also adjust constants this way. To keep the memory you should either save it to a file or serialize it by using the pickle module python has.

Comment: No problem leave a comment if you're having trouble. :)

Comment: fyi I just added my code above that seems to basically do the trick.  I looked at a bunch of Tree implementations (very helpful, thanks for the advice!).  I found the intuition very helpful, but I ultimately found writing my own short functions like this that had an equivalent "search" and "traverse" operations seemed to do the trick.  Thanks again!